# Want to know if possible to use google image search in custom search engine

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

As title says I'm trying to create a custom search engine (using Google's "Custom search") and was wondering if I can use google's image search within my custom one. For instance i have one website allocated to my custom engine "www.topman.com" and would want a user to be able to upload an image of a tshirt and find a link within topman that has a similiar styled tshirt. Thankyou in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google Custom Search does not have "search by image" functionality.